# Oval & ellipse in Java

Tags: java, swing, 2d

Ellipse has a somewhat nifty method called intersects and you can see if it intersects with a rectangle. Two questions. One is out of curiosity..

Does anyone know what the reasoning behind that way?

Second, is there anything similar I can use with just a filled oval?

Answer (score 0):

> Second, is there anything similar I can use with just a filled oval?

Use the `Graphics2d.fill(Shape)` method for your painting. Then you can use an `Ellispe2D` and its `intersects()` method.